# Does *tourist* have a derogatory connotation of *inexperienced* or any other meanings in the clip of Ice Age3?

Tags: meaning, connotation, pejorative-language, semantics

As a major in tourism, I've already acknowledged that tourists' notoriety among the destination dwellers by taking pictures of anything,disregarding  the unwritten rules ... Here I will not go on to discuss it.

I noticed that the word *tourist* is loaded with other connotative emotion after I watched  *Ice Age: Dawn of the Dinosaurs*, *Rio(2011)*, and *The Tourist* starring Johnny Depp and Angelina Jolie.

Ice Age3 "00:40:12"

Also in *Rio* when Blue just arrived.  "00:13:18"

Now **just take the one in *Ice Age 3* for example**, Buck sneers, "Tourists!" after rescuing Manny and Diego in the nick of time when they are trapped in a carnivorous flower with digestive fluids.

I think, in this context, it means someone who is inexperienced, cf.a *newbie*,  - a frequently used slang word for someone who is new to a job or task, which is told by my American friend.

Does *tourist* have a derogatory connotation of *inexperienced* or any other meanings in the clip of Ice Age3?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tourist

Comment: I fail to see how this question is specific to English. Given the context, the word would have the exact same connotation in any language. The connotation arises *from* the context. In and of itself, the word just means what it means.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Will people say that "The guy is a tourist."when the one is not actually travelling in any other places?

Comment: @Ze_Rosita: as it has been pointed out to you (in the oldest answer), no one prevents people from saying "that guy is a child", "that guy is a rock", "that guy is God", even if that is not strictly true. This is called metaphorical usage. I am not sure what the question here is, and your editing it back and forth certainly doesn't help. Right now the question in the title doesn't match the question in the body at all. We can't be expected to keep up with this moving target. Please make your mind up, ask exactly one clear question, and stick to it. Thank you.

Comment: Could be worse.  I live in London and sometimes they're called 'tourons'.  Then again, we do encounter a suprisingly high number of 'visitors' who decide to exit a shop, get to the top of an escalator etc and then simply...stand still.

Comment: Edits aside, I fail to see how the original was NOT a valid question.  The O.P. inquired about the _usage_ of a word in the _English language_ - how in the world is that off-topic?  The FAQ says these kinds of questions are **welcomed**: •Usage, word choice, history of words’ development, dialect differences. As someone who grew up in a tourist town, I could immediately relate to what was asked: my dictionary defines _tourist_ as _someone who travels for pleasure_; yet two movies are using that word clearly outside of that scope. The question was apt, even if it didn't register with everyone.

Comment: I hope this gets re-opened, but people who think they're better than the average tourist think that they're "Travellers, not tourists".

Answer (score 1):

You're right that *tourist* can carry a negative connotation, but so can many other seemingly innocuous words. Cf. *youngster*, *newbie*, even *child* — when applied out of context. (For example, "He's such a child" would not be flattering to a grown-up.

In the sense that you are hearing it in those clips, it simply means someone who is inexperienced, non-practiced, or new to an activity, locale, or situation. Cf. *dilettante*. It may also carry the connotation of someone who is only interested in a "taste" of the entire experience, with no will to acquire the full knowledge of a place or activity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up in an area where our town's summer population quadrupled.  There, the word "tourist" was often used in the playfully derogatory way that you mention.

Tourists were the brunt of many inside jokes among the locals, like this one:

> Tourist: *This town is so quaint – but you must have a lot of odd folks around here, right?*
>   Local: *Oh, yes, but they're mostly gone by Labor Day.*

A local rock band even wrote a song called *I Hate Tourists* that humorously jabbed at the tribulations of dealing with a swelled population (crowded beaches, jammed parking lots, and a fellow with an out-of-state license plate who picked up a pretty hitchhiker, just before the singer had a chance to do so).

Since the influx of tourists was the lifeblood of our local economy, though, such resentment never ran very deep – we were equally thankful and petulant at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite likely that a native might be at least thought of as a tourist if he behaves like one.

I've lost count of the number of times I've asked people standing on the left of an escalator to move to the right. Even natives can forget the rule, particularly if they are chatting in a group.

Not sure I'd *call* them tourists to their faces, though.

---

Note for those who don't know London: there is a *written* rule that when using an escalator on the Tube (subway/underground railway) you stand on the right hand side to allow free passage on the left for those who want to walk and get to the end faster.